# Reconstruct equation by given solution

Tags: equation-solving, inverse

How can I reconstruct equation, which solution is given by series $\frac{x^{x-2}}{x!}$? The reverse task is straightforward with `Solve` function.

It seems pretty close to [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but not exactly it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the [generating function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html) of $\frac{k^{k-2}}{k!}$? If so: `Exp[-ProductLog[-x]] (1 + ProductLog[-x]/2)`.

Comment: @J.M., thanks, it is. Can you please specify how you received it? I tried GeneratingFunction[n^(n - 2)/n!, n, x], but it failed with "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered".

Comment: I had to derive that result semi-manually since *Mathematica* does not know about [the series expansion for powers of $W(x)/x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers).